# What does the '?' mean in react native

Tags: react-native

***React-Native*** code :

```
const StyledButton = styled.TouchableHighlight`
 width:250px;
 background-color:${props => (props.transparent ? "transparent" : "#f3f8ff")};
 padding:15px;
border:${props => (props.transparent ? "1px solid #f3f8ff " : 0)}
 justify-content:center;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 border-radius:24px
`;
StyledTitle = styled.Text`
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 3;
  color: ${props => (props.transparent ? "#f3f8ff " : "#666")};
`;
```

what does "`?`" mean in the lines below:

```
background-color:${props => (props.transparent ? "transparent" : "#f3f8ff")};

border:${props => (props.transparent ? "1px solid #f3f8ff " : 0)};

color: ${props => (props.transparent ? "#f3f8ff " : "#666")};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in react-native, it's a [if-else statement shorten style in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

> The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands: a condition followed by a question mark (?), then an expression to execute if the condition is truthy followed by a colon (:), and finally the expression to execute if the condition is falsy. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the if statement.

ex:

```js
function getFee(isMember) {
  return (isMember ? '$2.00' : '$10.00');
}

console.log(getFee(true));
// expected output: "$2.00"

console.log(getFee(false));
// expected output: "$10.00"

console.log(getFee(1));
// expected output: "$2.00"
```

```js
(props.transparent ? "transparent" : "#f3f8ff")

//meaning :

if(props.transparent==true){
    return "transparent"
}else{
    return "#f3f8ff"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have anything to do with react native.  It is the javascript ternary operator.

the syntax is

`condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator